How to check data hash in telegram mini app?
I create backend for mini app in telegram. I think, my code is correct, but i get wrong hash. Maybe I create data check string in wrong format:
auth_date=1721732407\nquery_id=AAGc5YMWAAAAAJzlgxb_3ABG\nuser={"id":377742748,"first_name":"Марк","last_name":"Аникин","username":"corray9","language_code":"en","allows_write_to_pm":true}

Is that correct? I'm not sure about serialization of user object.
My code:
func СheckTelegramAuth(initData string) bool {
    data, err := url.ParseQuery(initData)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error parsing initData:", err)
        return false
    }

    var keys []string
    for k := range data {
        keys = append(keys, k)
    }
    sort.Strings(keys)

    var dataCheckStrings []string
    for _, k := range keys {
        if k != "hash" { 
            dataCheckStrings = append(dataCheckStrings, fmt.Sprintf("%s=%s", k, data.Get(k)))
        }
    }
    dataCheckString := strings.Join(dataCheckStrings, "\n")

    fmt.Println(dataCheckString)

    h := hmac.New(sha256.New, []byte(os.Getenv("BOT_TOKEN")))
    h.Write([]byte("WebAppData"))
    secretKey := h.Sum(nil)

    h = hmac.New(sha256.New, secretKey)
    h.Write([]byte(dataCheckString))
    calculatedHash := hex.EncodeToString(h.Sum(nil))

    return calculatedHash == data.Get("hash")
}


Please [edit] your question to specifically and clearly define the problem that you are trying to solve. Additional details — including all relevant code, error messages, and debugging logs — will help readers to better understand your problem and [what you are asking].

try to swap secret and message here
must be:
h := hmac.New(sha256.New, []byte("WebAppData"))
    h.Write([]byte(os.Getenv("BOT_TOKEN")))



You can verify the integrity of the data (InitData) received by comparing the
received hash parameter with the hexadecimal representation of the
HMAC-SHA-256 signature of the data-check-string with the secret key,
which is the HMAC-SHA-256 signature of the bot's token with the
constant string WebAppData used as a key.

Your secret token will HMAC-SHA-256 signature of the bot's token with the constant string WebAppData not the other way around. You can replace them to make it work.
h := hmac.New(sha256.New, []byte("WebAppData"))
    h.Write([]byte(os.Getenv("BOT_TOKEN")))
    secretKey := h.Sum(nil)

Reference: https://core.telegram.org/bots/webapps#validating-data-received-via-the-mini-app

If you’re struggling with hash validation in your Telegram Mini App, I’ve got a solution for you. Check out this Validate Init data of Telegram Mini-App, which provides scripts for validating the data hash in both TypeScript and Python.
import crypto from 'crypto';

export async function checkValidateInitData(hashStr: string, initData: string, token: string, cStr = 'WebAppData'): Promise<boolean> {
    // Parse and sort the init data
    const sortedData = initData
        .split('&')
        .filter(chunk => !chunk.startsWith('hash='))
        .map(chunk => chunk.split('='))
        .sort((a, b) => a[0].localeCompare(b[0]))
        .map(([key, value]) => `${key}=${decodeURIComponent(value)}`)
        .join('\n');

    // Create secret key
    const secretKey = new Uint8Array(crypto.createHmac('sha256', cStr)
        .update(token)
        .digest());

    // Generate the data check hash
    const dataCheck = crypto.createHmac('sha256', new Uint8Array(secretKey))
        .update(sortedData)
        .digest('hex');

    // Compare the generated hash with the provided hash
    return dataCheck === hashStr;
}

